# How can I block a user's default home folder from mapping using group policy?

Tags: windows, group-policy

I'm delegated control over an OU, not an entire domain. On domain-level, each AD-User has a home folder mapped to Z: which I want to disable in my specific OU. I cannot modify the users' profiles manually because I don't have domain-level rights. Is anyone aware of a GPO that would disable the mapping in my OU?

Comment: Do you want to replace it with something else, or only keep Z: from becoming active?

Comment: @LPChip I don't want to replace it, I just want to block the mapping, i.e keep Z: from becoming active.

Comment: @Monika - You don't have the required permissions on the domain to acomplish what you want.

Comment: Is the mapping done via GPO or via the old-style user account "profile" parameter?

Comment: @u1686_grawity the mapping is via the old-style user account "profile" parameter, which I cannot modify directly.